# Passing subform textbox value back to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

What i am trying to do here is get the value from a `Textbox` on another form back to the main form.

In `FormMain` i have this function:

````
        private void FillList(string type, HtmlNode form)
        {
            try {

                var nodes = form.SelectNodes("//form" + type);
                if (nodes != null)
                {
                        foreach (HtmlNode elem in nodes)
                        {
                            var eleTY = elem.Attributes["type"] == null ? elem.Name.ToString() : elem.Attributes["type"].Value;
                            var eleNM = elem.Attributes["id"] == null ?
                                        elem.Attributes["name"] == null ? "" : "name"
                                        : "id";
                            var eleVU = elem.Attributes["id"] == null ?
                                        elem.Attributes["name"] == null ? "" : elem.Attributes["name"].Value
                                    : elem.Attributes["id"].Value;

                            var elePR = Helpers.PredictValue(eleVU);
                            var eleSL = "";

                            // check for select ...
                            if (eleTY == "select") {
                               FormInput fi = new FormInput(this, eleTY, eleVU);
                               fi.Show();
                            }

                            // first checked id then name ...
                            listViewMain.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                                elem.Attributes["type"]==null? elem.Name.ToString():elem.Attributes["type"].Value
                                ,
                                elem.Attributes["id"]==null?
                                    elem.Attributes["name"]==null? "":"name"
                                    :"id"
                                ,
                                elem.Attributes["id"]==null?
                                    elem.Attributes["name"]==null?"": elem.Attributes["name"].Value
                                : elem.Attributes["id"].Value
                                ,
                                eleNM + "|" + eleVU + "|" + eleSL + "|" + elePR
                        }));

                        // check the mode and append to it ...
                        if (comboBoxMode.Text == "mode_register") {
                            txtBoxUploadRegisterMacro.AppendText(eleNM + "|" + eleVU + "|" + eleSL + "|" + elePR + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        // check the mode and append to it ...
                        if (comboBoxMode.Text == "mode_login_and_post")
                        {
                            txtBoxUploadLoginAndPostMacro.AppendText(eleNM + "|" + eleVU + "|" + eleSL + "|" + elePR + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
                // handle ...
            }
        }

Once i have a ```select``` attribute another form will popup ```FormInput``` here i will input a value and hit a button, once the button is pressed i am trying to get the value of ```txtBoxInput.Text``` back to the ```FormMain``` i will hopefully store the returned value in the  ```eleSL``` variable.

My ```FormInput``` working:
````

```
public partial class FormInput : Form
{
    FormMain _formMain;
    public FormInput(FormMain formMain, string eleType, string eleName)
    {
        _formMain = formMain;
        InitializeComponent();
        lblTypeInput.Text = eleType;
        lblNameInput.Text = eleName;
    }

    private void BtnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // pass the value of txtBoxInput.Text back to FormMain here ...
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I can pass the instance of `FormMain` to `FormInput` but i'm clueless on how to get it back, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an instance of `FormMain` right, `_formMain`, why not use it? You could create a property on `FormMain` to then store this value and or pass it to a routine, you haven't clarified what you want to do. Can you please update your post to include what you are trying to do, it's unclear to me.

Comment: Can't you create a public property in FormMain for the data that you want to return, and set that in the BtnInput_Click() handler?

Comment: That's the simplest code you can provide to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Can't you add some properties to `FormInput` which you will access from the main form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of points to be made here. One is do you want the input form to be modal ( to wait until it is closed before proceeding)? If yes then you need to initialize the form and call `.ShowDialog()` when the input is needed. Otherwise you need to have the form showing with `.Show()` prior to calling the fill list method and just pull values from the reference to input form using properties.

### Input Form

```
public partial class InputForm : Form
{
    public InputForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get => textBox1.Text;
        set => textBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Either way the input form needs properties that exposes your data. That being either a single value, multiple values or a custom class.

### Modal Approach

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FillList()
    {
        var fi = new InputForm();
        fi.Value = textBox1.Text;  // set initial value from main form
        if (fi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fi.Value; // get input value back to main form
        }
    }
}
```

In order for this to work you need to set the `.DialogResult` property of each button in the input form accordingly, and set the `.AcceptButton` and `.CancelButton` properties of the input form. This will take care of closing the form when done, and setting the `DialogResult` return to `.ShowDialog()` in order to know if the user pressed [OK] or [Cancel].

### Non-Modal Approach

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    InputForm fi = new InputForm() { Value = "Default" };

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        fi.Show(this);
    }

    private void FillList()
    {   
        textBox1.Text = fi.Value; // grab whatever value the input form has
    }
}
```

In this approach, the input form isn't blocking the flow of the main form, but you don't know when a user has changed the value. When the method runs, it just pulls whatever value happens to be in the input form text box (and hence the `.Value` property).

Comment: Thank you guys, this helped a lot, i now understand it better, this was always a pain when coding! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this by adding a public property to your second form. This property getting can either return the string from the text box, or a variable if it has been set.

This is the more object-oriented approach as the second form controls what is returned.